# Accounts Negative for 6 months or more Regardless of Transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have few accounts

```
Select * from Trans;

AccountID PostDate    Description   Amount 
1         07/01/2016  deposit       10.00
1         07/09/2016  withdrawal    -15.00
```

Second Account:

```
AccountID PostDate    Description   Amount 
2         07/01/2016  deposit       10.00
2         07/13/2016  withdrawal    -20.00
2         01/05/2017  deposit       8.00
```

Third Account:

```
AccountID PostDate    Description   Amount 
3         07/05/2016  deposit       10.00
3         07/19/2016  deposit       20.00
3         08/28/2016  withdrawal    -45.00
```

Fourth Account:

```
AccountID PostDate    Description   Amount 
4         01/05/2016  deposit       10.00
4         01/19/2016  withdrawal    -20.00
4         09/28/2016  deposit       40.00
4         10/01/2016  withdrawal    -50
```

I am looking for all accounts that are negative for 6 months or more consecutively regardless of whether a deposit came in and account stayed negative. If the deposit made the running balance positive then obviously I need to exclude that account.

I need a general query...as I have more than the above two accounts in trans table.

The query should pick the AccountID 1 as it is negative for more than 180 days. It should pick up AccountID 2 as it is negative since 07/13/2016. It was negative -10 in July and although a deposit came, it still stayed negative -2 in January 2017. It should not pick up AccountID 3 because the balance is negative but it went negative on 08/28/2016 and that means it is negative for 148 days only. I dont want to pick up Account '4' as well. Althought it was consecutively negative for 6 months or more and also currently it is negative....but I want to get accounts whose running balance is negative on all days between 01/23/2017 - 07/23/2016.

Thanks

Comment: What does "for more than 180 days" mean? Do you need to pick up an account that had a negative balance for 1.5 years, from July 2013 to January 2015? Or only accounts that have a negative *current* balance (as of `SYSDATE`), and that have had a negative balance at all times for the past 180 days? **Also**: What version of Oracle are you using? Different versions have different tools available. (If you don't know, run `select * from v$version`).

Comment: Do you have a typo on the table for Account 3? It seems you show negative amounts for withdrawals and positive for deposits, but for Account 3 you have a withdrawal of 20.00 (positive) and a deposit of -45.00, what does that mean?

Comment: yes. Any account that is negative for 6 months or longer but it currently needs to be negative. For Example: Account '55' is negative from July 2013 to January 2017. I need to pick that. But Account '66' which was negative from July 2013 to December 2016 but now it turned positive in Jan 2017. I do not want to pick that. I am running Oracle 12c. And I fixed the typo in Account 3. Thanks

Comment: Can there be two transactions posted on the same date?  Should balance be computed per transaction or per day (e.g. if the balance peeks above 0 due to a morning transaction, but goes negative before end of day, what does that mean)?

Comment: There can be more than 1 transaction per day. TransID is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE trans ( AccountID, PostDate, Description, Amount ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2016-07-01', 'deposit',     10.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2016-07-09', 'withdrawal', -15.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-07-01', 'deposit',     10.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-07-13', 'withdrawal', -20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2017-01-05', 'deposit',      8.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-07-05', 'deposit',     10.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-07-19', 'deposit',     20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-08-28', 'withdrawal', -45.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2016-01-05', 'deposit',     10.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2016-01-19', 'withdrawal', -20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2016-09-28', 'deposit',     40.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2016-10-01', 'withdrawal', -50.00 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT accountid
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM( amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY postdate )
           AS balance
  FROM   trans t
)
GROUP BY accountid
HAVING MAX( balance ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY postdate ) < 0
AND    (  MAX( postdate ) <= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 180
       OR MAX( CASE WHEN postdate >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 180
                    THEN balance - amount END ) < 0
       );
```

**Output**:

```
 ACCOUNTID
----------
         1 
         2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to calculate the balance on each day.  For that, use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by accountid order by postdate) as balance
from trans t;
```

Then, you want 180 days of the balance being positive or negative.  This is trickier.  Here is a brute force method:

```
with tb as (
       select t.*,
           sum(amount) over (partition by accountid order by postdate) as balance
       from trans t
      )
select distinct accountid
from tb
where tb.balance < 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from tb tb2
                  where tb2.accountid = tb.accountid and
                        tb2.balance > 0 and
                        tb2.postdate >= tb.postdate and tb2.postdate < tb.postdate + 180
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve this with MATCH_RECOGNIZE. It assumes `PostDate` may not have duplicates for any given account. (If there are several transactions on a given date, the time of the transactions will control how they are treated.)

The key is the `PATTERN` clause. We look for a sequence of transactions (including ALL rows for an Account, since we anchor with `^` and `$`), where the first 0 to (unknown) number of rows are unconstrained (the `a` rows), then we look for one row (`b`) with a negative balance and a date of 180 days or more before `trunc(SYSDATE)`, and all the remaining rows must have negative balance.

```
with
    trans ( AccountID, PostDate, Description, Amount ) as ( 
      select 1, to_date('07/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  10.00 from dual union all
      select 1, to_date('07/09/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'withdrawal', -15.00 from dual union all
      select 2, to_date('07/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  10.00 from dual union all
      select 2, to_date('07/13/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'withdrawal', -20.00 from dual union all
      select 2, to_date('01/05/2017', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,   8.00 from dual union all
      select 3, to_date('07/05/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  10.00 from dual union all
      select 3, to_date('07/19/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  20.00 from dual union all
      select 3, to_date('08/28/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'withdrawal', -45.00 from dual union all
      select 4, to_date('01/05/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  10.00 from dual union all
      select 4, to_date('01/19/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'withdrawal', -20.00 from dual union all
      select 4, to_date('09/28/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'deposit'   ,  40.00 from dual union all
      select 4, to_date('10/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yy'), 'withdrawal', -50    from dual
    )
-- End of test data; SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select AccountID
from   trans
match_recognize(
  partition by AccountID
  order     by PostDate
  pattern   ( ^ a* b c* $ )
  define    b as b.PostDate <= trunc(sysdate) - 180 and sum(Amount) < 0,
            c as                                        sum(Amount) < 0
)
;

 ACCOUNTID
----------
         1
         2

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: What happens if the account has been opened within the last 180 days and was opened with a negative balance?

Comment: @mt0 - I assume from the OP's statement of the requirement that such an account should not be included. Regardless, it is not included in the output from this query.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized 12c is in lower environment only. Will go live a month from now. So production database is using 11G.

Comment: @Amir - :-) So you do need a solution with analytic functions after all. I learned some time ago that if we are going to use analytic functions, it is better not to mix them with aggregate functions. I will post a solution using only analytic functions, if I can write it soon and it's not too complicated. (The other solutions posted so far may be correct, but they do mix analytic and aggregate, which may be a drag on performance.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet also. It would also suffice your requiement. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT b.acc
FROM
  (SELECT row_number() over(partition BY a.acc order by dt DESC) nr,
    SUM(a.amt) over(partition BY a.acc order by 1 DESC) sm,
    row_number() over(partition BY a.acc,tp order by a.dt DESC) dt1,
    a.*
  FROM
    (SELECT 1 acc, '2016-07-01' dt, 'deposit' tp, 10.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2016-07-09' dt, 'withdrawal' tp, -15.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2016-07-01' dt, 'deposit' tp, 10.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2016-07-13' dt, 'withdrawal' tp, -20.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2017-01-05' dt, 'deposit' tp, 8.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2016-07-05' dt, 'deposit' tp, 10.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2016-07-19' dt, 'deposit' tp, 20.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2016-08-28' dt, 'withdrawal' tp, -45.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '2016-01-05' dt, 'deposit' tp, 10.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '2016-01-19' dt, 'withdrawal' tp, -20.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '2016-09-28' dt, 'deposit' tp, 40.00 amt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '2016-10-01' dt, 'withdrawal' tp, -50.00 amt FROM dual
    )a
  )b
WHERE (b.nr                                       = 1
OR b.dt1                                          =1)
AND b.sm                                          < 0
AND b.tp                                         <> 'deposit'
AND (TRUNC(sysdate) - to_date(b.dt,'yyyy-mm-dd')) > 180;
```